# Z3 Solving verilog assign statement

Tags: z3, smt

I ran the below code in z3 (java api):

```
BitVecExpr a = ctx.mkBVConst("a",8);
BitVecExpr b = ctx.mkBVConst("b",8);
BitVecExpr c = ctx.mkBVConst("c",8);
BitVecExpr d = (BitVecNum) ctx.mkNumeral("11",ctx.mkBitVecSort(8));
Solver s = ctx.mkSolver();
s.add(ctx.mkEq(c,ctx.mkBVXOR(a,b)));
s.add(ctx.mkEq(c,d));   
Model m = s.getModel();
System.out.println("m.eval(a) " + m.eval(a,false)); /*m.eval(a) 0 */
System.out.println("m.eval(b) " + m.eval(b,false));  /*m.eval(b) 11 */
System.out.println("m.eval(c) " + m.eval(c,false));  /*m.eval(c) 11 */
```

My questions are:

1. How to pass a hexadecimal value for `d`? Does it only take a decimal value?
2. Is there any other way to pass bit value to `d`?

Comment: I do not see how the title is related to the body of the question, how does the posted code related to a verilog assign?

Comment: actually verilog code for above z3 is: assign c = a & b. All are 8 bit and i want c which is output to be decimal 11

Comment: Can't try it right now, but did you try to pass hex numbers prefixed with 0x ? The SMT theory allows those, but I'm not sure that mkNumeral is hooked up to the right parts to do that.

Comment: i tried: BitVecExpr d = (BitVecNum) ctx.mkNumeral("0xa",ctx.mkBitVecSort(8));               But its not working for me.

Comment: @ChristophWintersteiger if 0x is not working with mkNumeral. Then according to you what should be right method to implement that.

Comment: There is no "right" method, the parser simply doesn't support that at the moment. For small numbers (ints, longs) you can use ctx.mkBV(0x11, 8), otherwise you need to convert it to decimal first.

Comment: @ChristophWintersteiger Thanks i will try ctx.mkBV(0x11,8) or convertion logic.